# Swipe and Hide comments missing in appium

Tags: java, android, mobile, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am new to appium.I would like to use `driver.hideKeyboard()` and `drive.swipe()` comments in appium.However when I try to use these comments in eclipse,it is thorowing error as

> The method swipe() is undefined for the type WebDriver

Hide also I am getting same error.I think I need to import something in the drive.Could you please guide me what I need to do?

```
public void Appium() throws MalformedURLException
{
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("device", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "5.1.1");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried following.It is working fine.

```
AppiumDriver driver;
{
driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);
}

public void()
{
driver.hideKeyboard();
}
```

Above appium driver I am able to get swipe and hide functions.

Answer (score 0):

Change your driver type to AppiumDriver. Like this:

```
AppiumDriver driver;
```

and then

```
driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```